# Parsing xml document Java "cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm going through a tutorial on how to parse an xml document with java and encountering a problem. I am getting the error "dom cannot be resolved" I know it has something to do with the way I am declaring the variables and being out of scope but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I will post the relevant parts below:

```
package com.xmlparse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.entities.Employee;



public class XmlParser
{

private void parseXmlFile(){
    //get the factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();



    try {

        //Using factory get an instance of document builder
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
    Document dom = db.parse("test.xml");


    } catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch(SAXException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 private void parseDocument() {

    Document dom = db.parse("test.xml");

    //get the root element
    Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

    //get a nodelist of elements
    NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("Employee");
    if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

            //get the employee element
            Element el = (Element)nl.item(i);

            //get the Employee object
            Employee e = getEmployee(el);


            //add it to list
            myEmpls.add(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code seems incomplete + what kind of error are you talking about? Compilation error? Runtime error? (I assume it is compilation from the  error message - if so, in which line is there a compilation problem?)

Comment: I managed to fix the error, it was out of scope in the try block. And yes, I did not post all of the code. Basically I am trying to learn how to parse an xml document and grab the text associated with each tag and place those attributes in an object. The next step is going to be figuring out how to pass this over a http request but I have not gotten to that yet. So far I have been able to get it to recognize the number of objects but when I try to print the attributes to the console I get "nulls" for each value. If anyone has any advice that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `DocumentBuilder` `db` in different methods, you could declare `db` as a class member variable:

```
private DocumentBuilder db;
```

and initialize like so in `parseXmlFile`:

```
db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
```

Comment: ah sorry, it was "dom cannot be resolved" but your point still remains the same. I will try it out. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could change method signature like below and when call to it pass the created document builder instance.

```
private void parseDocument(DocumentBuilder db)
```